# Palm tree Queen

Tags: trees, palm

Why did the new middle fond of my queen palm tree drop down in a lazy position? I'm worried about them. I've got two queen palms that this issue has occurred most recently.

Comment: A picture of the situation would be helpful. Also more info about how you took care of the plant, and if some conditions changed recently (weather, transplant, drought, etc.).

Comment: it's possible that it's a flower stalk (I don't know the specific epithet for Cycad flower stems) As b.nota said, a picture will reveal much.

Comment: It is most likely a millennial fond. These fond's were coddled to much as children and now have developed a lack of appreciation of essential tasks like growing...